# Bash Insert line after find

Tags: bash

trying to write a Bash script. I have file:

```
### PHP Worker ############################################
php-worker:
  build:
    context: ./php-worker
...
```

I want to find the string `context: ./php-worker` and add ports after it:

```
        ports:
      - "6001:6001"
```

my try: `sed -i '/context: \./php-worker/a \- "6001:6001"' docker-compose.yml`
but there is an error `extra characters at the end of l command`

Help me please.

Comment: You would be far better off using a YAML parser that trying to use standard line-oriented tools.

Comment: Your problem seems to be the / in front of php-worker - terminating your address ("/regexp/"). See answer from Raman Sailopal

Answer (score 0):

Sed is probably not the most ideal of tools for editing yaml but with sed:

```
sed -r '/^.*context: \.\/php-worker$/a\\tports:\n\t- "6001:6001"' docker.yml
```

Use regular expressions and so use the -r flag of sed. ^ Signifies the start of the line and $ then end. You can then add \n to a new line and \t for a tab to the appended text.